# json_decode() expecting a string, I could only get an array

Tags: php, rest, json, slim

I'm using *Slim Framework*, trying to build a *REST API*. Long story short, I've been like for 4 hours looking for a solution for my problem, which it is that json_decode won't take as an argument the array that getBody() returns.

Using *Advanced REST Client for Chrome*, the error I get when I do a **post request** is:

```
Slim Application Error
The application could not run because of the following error:

Details

Type: ErrorException
Code: 2
Message: json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given
File: C:\xampp\htdocs\farmacias\index.php
Line: 100
Trace

#0 [internal function]: Slim\Slim::handleErrors(2, 'json_decode() e...', 'C:\xampp\htdocs...', 100, Array)
#1 C:\xampp\htdocs\farmacias\index.php(100): json_decode(Array)
#2 [internal function]: {closure}()
#3 C:\xampp\htdocs\farmacias\Slim\Router.php(172): call_user_func_array(Object(Closure), Array)
#4 C:\xampp\htdocs\farmacias\Slim\Slim.php(1222): Slim\Router->dispatch(Object(Slim\Route))
#5 C:\xampp\htdocs\farmacias\Slim\Middleware\Flash.php(86): Slim\Slim->call()
#6 C:\xampp\htdocs\farmacias\Slim\Middleware\MethodOverride.php(94): Slim\Middleware\Flash->call()
#7 C:\xampp\htdocs\farmacias\Slim\Middleware\ContentTypes.php(80): Slim\Middleware\MethodOverride->call()
#8 C:\xampp\htdocs\farmacias\Slim\Middleware\PrettyExceptions.php(67): Slim\Middleware\ContentTypes->call()
#9 C:\xampp\htdocs\farmacias\Slim\Slim.php(1174): Slim\Middleware\PrettyExceptions->call()
#10 C:\xampp\htdocs\farmacias\index.php(139): Slim\Slim->run()
#11 {main}
```

And my **piece of code**, being the line 100 the one with json_decode on it

```
// POST /localidades
$app->post('/localidades', function () use ($app){
    // Obtenemos el cuerpo del request, y lo decodificamos
    $request = $app->request();
    $body = $request->getBody();
    $input = json_decode($body);

    // Creamos y guardamos el registro
    $eloc = R::dispense('localidades');
    $eloc->nombre = (string)$input->nombre;
    $eloc->provincia = (string)$input->provincia;
    R::store($eloc);

    // Creamos y devolvemos JSON
    $app->response()->status(201);
    $app->response()->header('Content-Type','application/json');
    echo json_encode(R::exportAll($eloc));

});
```

If anyone could help me, I would be delighted. Of course I would also like to know if I'm doing something wrong or approaching the wrong way. I spend a lot of time looking for an answer and I couldn't find any.

Comment: And what does $request->getBody() return exactly now?

Comment: @mario If I do a var_dump($body);
I get --->
array(2) {
  ["nombre"]=>
  string(12) "General Pico"
  ["provincia"]=>
  string(1) "1"
}

Comment: And why and what part of that needs decoding in your opinion?

Comment: You wont believe I even paste THAT and NOT notice about it. I only needed to convert the array to object, and that's it. You were amazingly helpful, I'll be glad to mark you as the right answer if you post it like it. Thank you Mario! But the princess is in another castle haha

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already have decoded data in $input, so there is not need to decode anything there. You can also avoid the unnecessary castings as these are not needed in this scenario (PHP is a weakly typed language).